# QGis 3.28.2 changing attribute value

Tags: qgis, table

As you can see in the picture attached, in the column of ID is distributed with different values, I want to delete them and equate the values with the numbers I pictured in red. The numbers should be ongoing. It is not possible to do it manually, the table has 800 rows.

[image]

field calculator
[image]

Comment: Have you tried `$id` in the field calculator?

Comment: I do not know how to do that

Comment: https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/attribute_table.html#calculate-fields-values

Comment: Thank you, but i still cant do it. Just the first row is changing

Comment: @Erik Could you explain or show a picture of what I have to type?

Comment: I already did: `$id` is the expression you want to use.

Comment: Maybe you have the first row selected when you run $id?  If so, only the selected row would be attributed.  Clear your selection and try again?

Comment: Thank you @GBG and @Erik! It is working right now, but the first row starts with zero and not with 1, how can I change it?

Comment: `$id+1` it is then.

Comment: @Erik Thank you, it works now.